# Induced differential operator in long exact sequence of cohomology groups of differential complexes is well defined

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, differential-operators

In *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology, Bott & Tu* they claim that given a short exact sequence of differential complexes:

$$0\rightarrow A \overset{f} \rightarrow B \overset{g} \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$$
with $f,g$ being chain maps, there is a long exact sequence of cohomology groups:
[image]

They define the induced differential operator $d^{\ast}$ as follows. Given $c\in\ker d \cap C^{q}$ we have a $b\in B\cap B^q$ such that $g(b)=c$ and $db\in \ker g = \text{Im} f$. So, we have an $a\in A^{q+1}$ such that $f(a)=db$. We define $d^{\ast}([c])=[a]\in H^{q+1}(A)$.

They say that a simple diagram chasing shows that $d^{\ast}$ is well-defined on equivalence classes by for some reason I'm not able to see it. I've tried to prove that if $c'-c \in \text{Im} d \cap C^{q}$ such that $g(b)=c, \ g(b')=c'$ and $f(a)=db, \ f(a')=db'$ then $a'-a\in \text{Im} d \cap A^{q+1}$ but I am having a lot of trouble showing this. I would appreciate some hints about what I'm missing here.

Comment: In addition to the answers below, this can be found in most introductory books on algebraic topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given short *exact* sequence of differential complexes - and i [assume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitchell%27s_embedding_theorem) we have complexes of modules over a fixed ring, so that diagram chasing is possible - looks in detail as follows:

$\require{AMScd}$
$$
\begin{CD}
  @.   \vdots     @.   \vdots    @.    \vdots \\
@.     @A{d_A}AA       @A{d_B}AA       @A{d_C}AA       \\
0 @>>> \bbox[limegreen]{\ A^{q+1}\ }
                 @>f>> B^{q+1}   @>g>> C^{q+1}   @>>> 0\\
@.     @A{d_A}AA       @A{d_B}AA       @A{d_C}AA       \\
0 @>>> A^{q}     @>f>> B^q       @>g>> \bbox[yellow]{\ C^q\ }       @>>> 0\\
@.     @A{d_A}AA       @A{d_B}AA       @A{d_C}AA       \\
0 @>>> A^{q-1}   @>f>> B^{q-1}   @>g>> C^{q-1}   @>>> 0\\
@.     @A{d_A}AA       @A{d_B}AA       @A{d_C}AA       \\
  @.   \vdots     @.   \vdots    @.    \vdots \\
\end{CD}
$$

We define as in the question the map from the homology computed in the yellow entry, with values in the homology computed in the green entry:

- Pick some $\bbox[yellow]{\ c\ }$ in the yellow object.
- Since $g=g^q$ is surjective, lift $c$ to some $b\in B^q$.
- Build $db=d_Bb$, an element in $B^{q+1}$. This element is mapped to $0$ via $g$, so by exactness, it comes via $f$ from an element (which is unique) $\bbox[limegreen]{\ a\ }\in A^{q+1}$, determined via $fa=db$
- We define the connecting morphism, usually denoted by $\delta:H^\cdot(C)\to H^{\cdot+1}(A)$, as a map $c\to a$, more exactly, the class of $c$ goes to the class of $a$.

Why is it well defined?

- Why the $g$-lift $b$ of $a$ leads to no ambiguity? Pick an other lift, $b'$ of $c$ in $B^q$. We built the image $db'$ of $b'$ in $B^{q+1}$. Then pick $a'\in A^{q+1}$ so that $fa'=db'$. It remains to check that $a$ and $a'$ coincide as elements in $H(a)$. Indeed, from $g(b-b')=gb-gb'=c-c=0$, and from the exactness of the horizontal short exact sequence in level $q$ we obtain an $\alpha in A^q$ with
  $$
  f\alpha = b-b'\ .
  $$ Then:
  $$
  a-a'=d\alpha\ .
  $$ Why? The above relation is equivalent to the relation obtained from it by applying the injective / monomorphic $f$, and indeed:
  $$
  f(a-a')=fa-fa'=db-db'=d(b-b')=d\; f\alpha =f\; d\alpha\ .
  $$ So $\delta$ is well defined w.r.t. the choice of a $g$-lift.
- Why are boundaries mapped to zero? Assume we start with some $c=d\kappa$, $\kappa\in C^{q-1}$. Then we can lift $\kappa$ via $g$ in level $q-1$ to some $\beta$, so $g\beta=\kappa$. This means that $d\beta$ is a possible lift for $c=d\kappa$. We take it, any lift is equally good, we have cleared this above.
  We move to $B^{q+1}$ via $d$ and get $dd\kappa=0$, which uniquely lifts to $0\in A^{q+1}$. So boundaries in $C^q$ are mapped to zero.

$\square$

Comment: What if we take the lifts of $c, c'$ such that $[c]=[c']\in H^q(C)$? Then we can no longer say that $g(b-b')=c'-c$ is equal to zero and therefore $b-b'$ may not be in $\text{Im}f$. How do we show in that case that $a-a'\in \text{Im} d$?

Comment: Start with representatives $c,c'$ (both cycles) so that they correspond to the same class. Consider the difference (class) $c-c'$. It is a boundary. Which is mapped to zero, as shown above.